# Sending HTML formatted email via Outlook from Access

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba

Here is part of my code which works fine:

```
Dim objOutlook As New Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As MailItem
Dim Header as String
Dim Text As String
Dim EmailAddr as String

Set objOutlook = New Outlook.Application
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

I then define Header, text and EmailAddr

With objMail
    .To = EmailAddr
    .Subject = Header
    .Body = Text
    .Send
End with
```

I want to format the text as Arial 12pt.

What do I insert to achieve this?

On using your suggestion I first get an email with out the test text and in font Calibri. If I try to send it, I get an error message. On SAVE, I find that I also have in Drafts, the version of the email as you predicted - correct font and text. How can I get rid of the first email? Also any hints on changing to bold and italic? Is it just a case of writing a normal html document and slotting it in the coding?

Comment: re: error message - I just tried my code and it worked for me. If you were running the Access VBA code with Outlook closed then try it again with Outlook already open. re: Bold, etc. - Yes, just use the appropriate HTML tags in your `.HTMLBody` text.

Answer (score 3):

Based on a response to a thread [here](http://p2p.wrox.com/excel-vba/60103-excel-vba-send-email-html-message-body.html), it seems like the following might do the trick:

```
With objMail
    .To = EmailAddr
    .Subject = Header
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = "<span style=""font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt;"">This is a test.</span>"
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: When I try this:With objMail
    .To = "peter@mckeown-online.com"
    .NoAging = True
    .Display (True)
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = "<span style=""font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt;"">This is a test.</span>"
    .Save
    End With

Comment: @user2204315 Hint: Just [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19468875/edit) your question with additional information, then use a comment here to say "I've updated my question".